# How to dynamically define morph unassigned type in Laravel migrations

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, migration

I'm wondering about one particular subject:

I defined a relation via `morph`, then started to develop migration file, and all table primary keys have `BIGINT` type.

I doubt about supporting `BIGINT` in morphmigrate, because I saw this line in `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint` :

```
$this->unsignedInteger("{$name}_id");  // Line# (in 5.5): 1060
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You may explicitly add the required columns instead of using [`morphs`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_morphs) method

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $this->unsignedBigInteger("polymorphic_id");
    $this->string("polymorphic_type");
    $this->index(["polymorphic_id", "polymorphic_type"]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a solution, there's should be something to handle this by framework

Comment: the `morph` method (Line# (in 5.5): 1060) is just a wrapper for those three methods, I have called them explicitly and changed `unsignedInteger` to`unsignedBigInteger`. Laravel defines `morhps` with `unsignedInteger` by default, it's not a question of whether Laravel support `BIGINT`  or not.